# Django Admin - how to customize title with dynamic string

Tags: django-admin

I would like to customize the title used in the admin templates for a particular model-edit page. While I could modify the template, what I really want to do is to modify the context parameter 'title' that is passed in. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to override the change_view method of ModelAdmin in your own MyModelAdmin, passing in your custom title in the extra_context parameter like so:

```
from django.contrib.admin.util import unquote
from django.contrib.admin.options import csrf_protect_m
from django.db import transaction

@csrf_protect_m
@transaction.commit_on_success
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        obj = self.get_object(request, unquote(object_id)) # get the object if you need it
        extra_context = {'title': _('Change MYOBJ - %s') % (obj.SOME_TEXT) }
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do this, and it's easier than I thought for something that is not supported by django.

In your `Admin` class, add the following methods:

- `changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None)`
- `changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None)`
- `add_view(self, request, form_url='' extra_context=None)`
- `change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None)`
- `def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None)`
- `history_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None)`

Long list, I know. Override only what you need.

When overriding, just insert your title into the `extra_content` argument like so:

```
def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    if extra_context is None:
        extra_context = {}
    extra_context['title'] = 'My Custom Title'

    return super().changeform_view(
        request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

If you use it often, you could even create a mixin that overrides all of these methods and inserts your custom titles in.

[Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1338).